# Angular 7 search filter for dynamic nested object

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In my Angular 7 project, I get the below JSON data (nested structure) that has been displayed using *ngFor.

> JSON

```
[
 {
     1: [
        { 
            "name" : "A"
        },
        { 
            "name" : "B"
        },
        { 
            "name" : "C"
        }
     ],

     2: [
        { 
            "name" : "D"
        },
        { 
            "name" : "E"
        },
        { 
            "name" : "A"
        }
     ]
 }
]
```

> Displaying code

```
<div *ngFor="let data of result | keyvalue">
        <div> 
                {{data.key}}
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let innerData of data.value;">
           {{innerData.name}}
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to do the filter for the nested data structure using an angular pipe. For example: If I give the value of the name "A". The result should be as below.

> Expected filter result

```
[
 {
     1: [
        { 
            "name" : "A"
        }
     ],

     2: [
        { 
            "name" : "A"
        }
     ]
 }
]
```

Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

is there some reason to filter it? If you just don't want to display elements in some condition, I think `*ngIf` is not a bad option.

ts:

```
searchOption = ''
```

html:

```
    <div *ngFor="let innerData of data.value;">
      <ng-container *ngIf="innerData.name === searchOption">
        {{innerData.name}}
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need to do the filter option (Search option has to be given in the top of the list)

Comment: By default, all the data should be displayed, when ever we type, list will be filtered out and display.